# How to use most recent Python after installation?

Tags: python

I installed the most recent version of Python 3, but when I command

```
python
import sys
sys.version
```

It says the version I am using is 2.7. How do I change this?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: I am using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: try `python3` instead of `python`

Answer (score 4):

Use the command "python3" instead of "python".

In linux/unix, you can use the command "which python", and it will tell you the path of your python installation.

Then you can use the command "which python2" and "which python3" to see the paths of python2 and python3.

If python3 is not in your path and it is installed, then you will have to modify your system `PATH` variable.

Comment: `python` may be a symbolic link pointing to `python2`. You can check it out with `ls -l $(which python)`.

Answer (score 1):

if there are more than one version of python installed in your machine you can type the version following the "python" keyword to call that particulat version

if I just type python it goes to python2.7

```
root@debian:/home/anand/Documents/nodeschool# python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
```

but if i type python3 then it goes to python 3

```
root@debian:/home/anand/Documents/nodeschool# python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

if you are curious how many versions of python are available to you. You can press tab after typing python

```
anand@debian:~$ python
python      python2     python2.7   python3     python3.4   python3.4m  python3m
```